# async.series functions are not completing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sails.js, waterline, async.js

I am facing an weird problem with `async.js`. I am explaining the whole scenario. I have two tables in database. Let one be `X` with 5 rows and another be `Y` with 2840 rows. As my project is in `sails.js` I am using `waterline` as ORM. I am running three functions in `async.series`. First one for fetching all the rows from table `X`, second one for fetching all the rows from table `Y`. In the third function I am running `async.eachSeries` over all the rows of `Y` that is fetched in second function and calling an external POST api. So the overall flow is,

```
async.series([
    function( callback1 ){
        // Fetch all rows from `X`
    },
    function( callback1 ){
        // Fetch all rows from `Y`
    },
    function( callback1 ){
        async.eachSeries(allRowsOfY, function(item, callback2){
            // Call an external POST api.
        },
        function(err){

        });
    },
], 
function( err ){
    // Do something
});
```

Problem is, even if `Y` has 2840 rows, only around 600 api calls are being made, then `async.series` is beginning to run from the very first. And this incident is going on and on. Why is this happening?

Comment: you'll have to do more debugging on your own. Either you're counts are off, or something is stopping the eachSeries. That or you are getting caught by some kind of rate-limiting at the api endpoint.

Comment: From what I experienced, `async` is prone to fail when you call one of these `callback1`s multiple times. Is it possible that this happened?

Comment: I am calling `callback1` exactly once from each of the async.series functions.

Comment: @taufique frome where comes `allRowsOfY` array?

Answer (score 1):

Move async.series to callback section when you have all needed data

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
      // Fetch all rows from `X`
      callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback) {
      // Fetch all rows from `Y`
      callback(null, ['two', 'three', 'four']);
    }
  ],
  function(err, allRowsOf) {
    async.eachSeries(allRowsOf[1], function(item, callback) { // take second element from array of results creates by async.series
        console.log('call external POST API with: ', item)
        callback() // call callback without error if everything is OK
      },
      function(err) {
        if (err) console.log('error', err)
      });
  });
```

Comment: I would have to check if it works. But can you point me out what was the problem?

Comment: @taufique `allRowsOfY ` was not accesible for `asyns.series`